# How to make a dropdown menu transition with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, css-transitions

I have created a responsive navigation-bar/menu but I want it to appear with a sliding animation from the top to the bottom when the needed button is presed. The menu does appear on itself but it completely ignores the transitioni have set it to execute. I tried multiple methods - using webkit library, using the change in height method, etc. It appears that none of them work with my code. If anyone can help, please reach to me.

```js
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.dot_a');
const navbarLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-list');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.pro_column1 {
  width: 15%;
}

.pro_column2 {
  width: 85%;
}

.nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  /*opacity: 60%;*/
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 850px;
  /*background:#3c6382;
  /*box-shadow:0px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);*/
  /*border: solid black 2px;*/
}



.nav a {
  color: #747d8c;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 27px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  -webkit-animation: 1s ease-in forwards;
}

.dot_a {
  padding: 25px 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;

  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

i {
  /*float: right;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #747d8c;
  padding: 25px 5px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  .nav a {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;

    
    
  }
  .dot_a {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .nav {
    width: 90%;
    
    
  }
  .dot {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }


  .nav-list{  
    display: none;
    max-height: 0;
    -webkit-animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;


  }

  .nav-list.active {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    max-height: fit-content;
    -webkit-animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;

  
  }

}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Начало</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.jpg">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="IndexStyle.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d2896764d5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<nav class="nav">
    <div class="dot_a">
      <span class="dot" style="background-color: transparent; width: 5px; height: 5px;"></span>
      <span class="dot" style="background-color: #ff4757;"></span>
      <span class="dot" style="background-color: #ffa502"></span>
      <span class="dot" style="background-color: #2ed573;"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="nav-list">
      <a class="anchors" href="Index.html"><i class="fas fa-house-damage"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;НАЧАЛО</a>
      <a class="anchors" href="HtmlPage.html"><i class="fas fa-code"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;HTML&CSS</a>
      <a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="fas fa-tools"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ИНСТРУМЕНТИ</a>
      <a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ЗАДАЧИ</a>
      <a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="far fa-address-card "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ЗА НАС</a> 
    </span>
  </nav>
</center>
  <script src="ResponsiveMenu.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A easy way to do it is with CSS, for this cases i always use [Animista](https://animista.net/play/entrances/slide-in/slide-in-top). Try adding this to your CSS file and then add the class `slide-in-top` to your menu container.

```
.slide-in-top {
-webkit-animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
        animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}


@-webkit-keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! I've got one more question tho ... It makes a sliding animation on the <a> elements and i want it on the whole navigation ... I will update the code and feel free to give it a look if you have time. <3 @Giacomo Contessi

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use bootstrap to make an easy and fast navbar transition but you need to know what classes to put. to get bootstrap working put this in your head

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```